# How to catch custom events from two custom element?

Tags: javascript, events, lit-element

I have created a custom lit-component which has a condition and if the condition is false it should listen to and event which if the condition is true this element fires after clicking on it. After I created tow of this element one set to true the other to false after I fire the event the one which has the property set to false wont catch it even though I am bubbling the event.

What am I missing to be able to catch the events form the other element?

**In the view element I am calling the custom-element two times with different props:**

*The isRoot property is deciding if the element is fireing or listening to the event*

```
<custom-element isRoot>Hello From Item</custom-element>
<custom-element>Hello From Item</custom-element>
```

**custom-element.js:**

```
class CustomElement extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
        isRoot: { type: Boolean },
    }
  }

  static get styles() {
    return [
      css`
        span {
          width: 20px;
          display: inline-block;
          text-align: center;
          font-weight: bold;
        }
      `
    ];
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <slot @click=${this.handleClick}></slot>
    `;
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.isRoot = false;
    this.addEventListener("my-event", this.handleLoaded);
  }

  firstUpdated(changedProperties) {
  }

  handleLoaded(e){
    console.log("Listening")
    console.log(this.isRoot); 
    if(!this.isRoot){
        console.log(e.bubbles);
    }


  }

  handleClick(){
    if(this.isRoot){
        console.log("Fireing")
        let myEvent = new CustomEvent("my-event", { 
            detail: { message: 'my-event happened.' },
            bubbles: true, 
            composed: true });
          this.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
    }
  }
}

window.customElements.define('custom-element', CustomElement);
```

Comment: Events do not bubble to siblings. You need an ancestor-descendant relationship.

Comment: Is it possible somehow to send events to siblings?

Comment: Not with the Javascript event bubbling/listening mechanisms. You'd have to listen on an ancestor of both and kind of implement a pub/sub- or messenger pattern. Using Javascript events for component communication is great because of the decoupling, but unfortunately can only work in ancestor/descendant scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Here I tried to illustrate your code as working example. If it's not fit your need please comment then we can work on.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/litelement-testt-iguwbg?file=index.js)

```
import { LitElement, html, css } from '@polymer/lit-element'; 



class CustomElement extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
        isRoot: { type: Boolean }
    }
  }


  render() {
    return html`
      <slot @click="${this.handleClick}"></slot><span>${this.isRoot}</span>

    `;
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.addEventListener("my-event", this.handleLoaded);
  }

  handleLoaded(e){

    console.log("Listening", this.isRoot,' Message: ')
    if(!this.isRoot){
        console.log(e);
    }


  }

  handleClick(e){
    console.log('clicked')
    if(this.isRoot){
        console.log("Fireing",'1---', this.isRoot)
        let myEvent = new CustomEvent("my-event", { 
            detail: { message: 'my-event happened.' }
           });
          this.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
    }
  }

}

window.customElements.define('custom-element', CustomElement);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your effort :D I just managed to get around this problem by capturing the event on the parent element. After I got the event I evaluate it and I send it to all my custom components which are listening to it. I send the events value to a property which I added to the custom component :)